# New users defined in Jazz for Service Management 1.1.2 cannot access Tivoli Common Reporting

Tags: dynamic, tivoli, ibm-jazz, workload-scheduler

I defined new users in Jazz for Service Management 1.1.2 but cannot access Tivoli Common Reporting. Anybody could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to perform the following steps:

```
1.  Log into JazzSM portal (ex: smadmin user)
2.  Click on Reporting->Common Reporting
3.  Click on Launch->Administration
4.  Click on Security tab
5.  Click on Cognos directory
6.  Select Authors and then go to set properties
7.  Click on Members tab
8.  Click on Add link
9.  Click on VMMProvider
10. Click on Search link
11. Search for new users/groups and add them into Selected entries
12. Again click on Directory
13. Click on Cognos
14. Select "All authenticated users" group and add into Selected entries
15. Click Ok
16. Log out from JazzSM portal and re-login with new user
17. Open Reporting->Common Reporting.
```

If you cannot display the Launch > Administration menu, as requested in the procedure linked in step 1, see the instructions documented in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21514429